# how can I loop through a unciode json string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get the following string returned by the CBOE options api:

```
{u'inputs': {u'stock_price_max': 50.0, u'high_low_stock_max': None, u'time_frame': u'middle', u'hv30_max': None, u'high_low_stock_min': None, u'symbols': None, u'hv30_min': None, u'low_strike': 3.0, u'high_strike': 4.0, u'industry_codes': None, u'spread_ask_price_max': None, u'stock_price_min': 10.0}, u'output': [{u'stock_price': 43.2, u'stock_hi_lo_percent': 72.9651, u'symbol': u'EWZ', u'industry_code': 55501010, u'max_gain': 0.52, u'high_strike_otm_percent': 0.463, u'low_strike_otm_percent': 2.7778, u'spread_ask': 0.48, u'spread': u'43/42 Put', u'expiry': u'2019-04-18', u'max_gain_to_spread_ask_percent': 108.3333, u'hv30': 27.3836}, {u'stock_price': 41.37, u'stock_hi_lo_percent': 21.7957, u'symbol': u'FXI', u'industry_code': 55501010, u'max_gain': 0.26, u'high_strike_otm_percent': 0.8944, u'low_strike_otm_percent': 2.103, u'spread_ask': 0.24, u'spread': u'41/40.5 Put', u'expiry': u'2019-05-17', u'max_gain_to_spread_ask_percent': 108.3333, u'hv30': 20.2925}
```

I want to loop through it and place elements into cells in a Google spreadsheet. I have this code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint);
  var data = response.getContentText();
  sheet.getRange("A8").setValue(data);
}
```

This puts the entire string into cell A8.

I have tried to loop through the string with

```
for (i = 0; i < jsonlen; i++) {
    sheet.getRange("A:A").setValaue(data['output']['symbol']);
}
```

This returns "undefined". So problems are:
1) how can I extract the elements I need form the "output" part of the string
2) put the symbols into A3, A4 etc then stock_price into B3, B4 etc
3) how to identify the length of the string in order to make the loop work correctly
until the string has been entirely looped over?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is the output correct? Can you verify that, because maybe the response is a JSON object (which is easier to work with)), and what you are saying that the API returns is a string but it has a strange format for the '[' and '{'.

Comment: thanks Kessy. Yes you are right, I fixed the unicode into proper json with JSON.parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values of `symbol` and `stock_price` the property of `output` and want to put them to the columns "A" and "B" of the active Spreadsheet, respectively.
- You want to put the values from the row 3.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- the property of `output` has an array. And `symbol` and `stock_price` are in the array.

  - So at first, it is required to prepare the values for putting to Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  var values = data.output.map(function(e) {return [e.symbol, e.stock_price]});
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(3, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this case, the values are put to the row 3 of column "A" and "B" on the active sheet.

#### Note:

- In your case, if `data` is actually the string value of `{u'inputs': {###}, u'outputs': [###]}` which has the unicode literal of python 2, `u` is required to be replaced. So in this case, please put `data = JSON.parse(data.replace(/u\'|\'/g, "\"").replace(/None/g, "null"));` before `var values = data.output.map(function(e) {return [e.symbol, e.stock_price]});`. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: thank you so much this works great. I have learned a lot. One slight modification as you suggest above: var data =  JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); and that gets the job done. Very grateful!

Comment: @user1903663 Thank you for replying and adding the information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Also I modified the script. Thank you, too.